# Why do you multiply by the integrating factor when solving differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equations of the form
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x)
$$
can be solved by multiplying both sides of the equation by the 'integrating factor' $e^{\int p(x) \, dx}$. This transforms the equation to
\begin{align}
&e^{\int p(x) \, dx}\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{\int p(x) \, dx}p(x)y = e^{\int p(x) \, dx}q(x) \\
\implies &\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\int p(x) \, dx}y) = e^{\int p(x) \, dx}q(x) \, \tag{*}\label{*}.
\end{align}
This makes the equation much easier to solve, since we can integrate both sides of $\eqref{*}$ and proceed from there. However, while it is not too difficult to verify that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\int p(x) \, dx}y)= e^{\int p(x) \, dx}\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{\int p(x) \, dx}p(x)y \, ,
$$
it still seems that the 'multiply by $e^{\int p(x) \, dx}$' trick has been pulled out of a hat. In this post, I present a way of arriving at the above method in a way that seems less ad hoc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is exposition, not a question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The integrating factor method is based upon what might be termed the 'reverse product rule'. First, note that any differential equation of the form
$$
f(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + f'(x)y=g(x)
$$
may be rewritten as
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)y)=g(x)  \, .
$$
For example,
\begin{align}
&\sin(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + \cos (x)y = x^2 \\
\implies &\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(x)y) = x^2 \\
\implies &\sin(x)y = \int x^2 \, dx \\
\implies &\sin(x)y = \frac{x^3}{3}+C \\
\implies &y = \frac{x^3}{3\sin(x)} + \frac{C}{\sin (x)} \, .
\end{align}
So when we have a differential equation on the form
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x) \tag{1}\label{1} \, ,
$$
we want to convert it to
$$
f(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + f'(x)y=g(x) \, , \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
since $\eqref{2}$ boils down to
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)y)=g(x) \, .
$$
This is where the integrating factor steps in. Let $I(x)$ be the integrating factor, the multiplier that helps us get from $\eqref{1}$ to $\eqref{2}$. If we multiply $\eqref{1}$ by $I(x)$, we get
$$
I(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+I(x)p(x)y=I(x)q(x) \, .
$$
If the integrating factor is of the correct form, then we should now be able to rewrite the LHS as
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(I(x)y) \, .
$$
This tells the condition that $I(x)$ must satisfy: we require that $\frac{d}{dx}(I(x)y)$ equals $I(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+I(x)p(x)y$. To reiterate, multiplying a differential equation by the integrating factor should allow us to rewrite the LHS as the derivative of the product of two functions. This means that
$$
I(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + I'(x)y = I(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+I(x)p(x)y \, .
$$
This condition boils down to $I'(x)=I(x)p(x)$. Hence,
\begin{align}
&p(x) = \frac{I'(x)}{I(x)} \\
\implies & \int p(x) = \ln|I(x)| \\
\implies & I(x) = e^{\int p(x) \, dx} \, .
\end{align}
This solution can be verified by plugging $I(x)=e^{\int p(x) \, dx}$ into the equation
$$
I(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+I(x)p(x)y=I(x)q(x) \, .
$$
For ease of notation, let $P$ be an antiderivative of $p$, so that $I(x)=e^{\int p(x) \, dx}=e^{P(x)}$. The above equation is thus
$$
e^{P(x)}\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{P(x)}p(x)y = e^{P(x)}q(x) \, .
$$
We have fulfilled our objective of arriving at an equation of the form
$$
f(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + f'(x)y=g(x) \, ,
$$
with $f(x)=e^{P(x)}$ and $g(x)=e^{P(x)}q(x)$. Therefore, our work is done.

Comment: Not to be disrespectful or something, but isn't that exactly what Euler did? And pretty much exactly what is taught in a basic ODE class?